# Is it correct mysqldump --add-drop-database generate !40000?

Tags: mysql

I am using MySql v 6.1.7601. I was dumping a database trough this command:

```
mysqldump -u USERNAME -pPASSWORD --routines --add-drop-database --databases myDatabase> ...pathToSavedFile.sql
```

I was expecting to have

```
DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS myDatabase;
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS myDatabase;
USE myDatabase;
```

... create table code ...

Instead, I am having this:

```
/*!40000 DROP DATABASE IF EXISTS `myDatabase` */;
CREATE DATABASE /*!32312 IF NOT EXISTS*/ 'myDatabase' /*DEFAULT ....
```

How can I set to display properly (clear) the DROP and CREATE sentences ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is a version marker for mysql. `/*!<version> <command> */` will only run if the internal mysql version is greater than `<version>` (in this case, mysql 4.0).

There is literally nothing wrong with the dump, and this is expected.